# Why am I getting duplicate edges for this sobel filter implementation in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to implement a sobel filter for a course assignment in C cuda. I can't figure out why I'm getting duplicate (repeated) edges at regular intervals of 96px apart. Please find attached my code, and the input and output images. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have spent 2 days trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. Please note that I've only implemented the x-direction of sobel filter, and will implement the y-direction once I figure out the current problem.

convolve_kernel.cu (sobel filter cuda kernel)

```
#ifndef _SOBEL_KERNEL_H_
#define _SOBEL_KERNEL_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include "sobel.h"

#define TILE_SIZE 14
#define MASK_WIDTH 3
#define DEFAULT_THRESHOLD 8000
//extern __constant__ float Mcx[MASK_WIDTH][MASK_WIDTH];

// Matrix multiplication kernel thread specification
__global__ void convolveKernel(Matrix pic_device, Matrix P, Matrix Mcx, unsigned char* cudaFail_d)
{
  //printf("Hello\n");
  
  //printf("pic: %d\n", Mcx.elements[1]);
  // load tile into shared memory
  int tx = threadIdx.x;
  //printf("blockdim.x: %d, blockdim.y: %d, tile_size: %d\n",blockDim.x, blockDim.y, TILE_SIZE);
  int ty = threadIdx.y;
  __shared__ int Ms[TILE_SIZE+(MASK_WIDTH-1)][TILE_SIZE+(MASK_WIDTH-1)];
  int row_o = blockIdx.y*TILE_SIZE + ty;
  int col_o = blockIdx.x*TILE_SIZE + tx;
  int row_i = row_o - 1;
  int col_i = col_o - 1;
  int output_y = 0;
  

  //printf("pic_device: %d\n", pic_device.elements[4234]);
  if ((row_i >= 0) && (row_i < pic_device.height) && (col_i >= 0) && (col_i < pic_device.width))
  {
    Ms[ty][tx] = pic_device.elements[row_i*pic_device.width+col_i];
  }
  else
  {
    Ms[ty][tx] = 0;
  }
  __syncthreads();
  
  // Make sure you're only convolving within the current tile
  if(ty < TILE_SIZE && tx < TILE_SIZE)
  {
    int output_x = 0;
    int magnitude = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < Mcx.height; i++) 
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < Mcx.width; j++) 
      {
        //int current_row = ty + i;
        //int current_col = tx + j;
        //printf("Mcx: %i\n", Mcx[i][j]); 
            output_x += Ms[ty + i][tx + j] * Mcx.elements[i*Mcx.width + j];
            __syncthreads();
         // printf("mask width: %d\n", Mcx.width);
          //__syncthreads();
          //output_y += Mcx.elements[j*Mcx.width + i] * Ms[curr_neighbor_row][curr_neighbor_col];
          //__syncthreads();
      }
      
    }
    magnitude = (output_x*output_x);// + (output_y*output_y);
      
      /*
      if (blockIdx.x == 1 && blockIdx.y == 7)
      {
        printf("mag for row: %d, col: %d: %d\n", row_o, col_o, magnitude);
      }
      */
      //printf("%d\n", row_o);

        
      //}
      
      //else
      //{
       // P.elements[row_o * P.width + col_o] = 0;
        //__syncthreads();
     // }
      
    if (magnitude > DEFAULT_THRESHOLD)
      {
      if(row_o < P.height && col_o < P.width)
        
      {
        //if (((ty+1)<(TILE_SIZE+(MASK_WIDTH-1)))&&((tx+1)<(TILE_SIZE+(MASK_WIDTH-1))))
          P.elements[row_o * P.width + col_o] = (int)sqrt((float)(output_x*output_x));

      //printf("row_i: %d, col_i: %d, row_o: %d, col_o: %d\n", row_i, col_i, row_o, col_o);
      //printf("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
        }
      }
  }
}

#endif // #ifndef _SOBEL_KERNEL_H_
```

sobel.cu (main driver)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "string.h"
#include "sobel.h"

#define MASK_WIDTH 3
#define DEFAULT_THRESHOLD  8000
#define DEFAULT_FILENAME "BWstop-sign.ppm"
//__constant__ float Mcx[MASK_WIDTH][MASK_WIDTH];
// Allocate a device matrix of same size as M.
Matrix AllocateDeviceMatrix(const Matrix M)
{
  Matrix Mdevice = M;
  int size = M.width * M.height * sizeof(int);
  if(cudaMalloc((void**)&Mdevice.elements, size) != cudaSuccess)
  {
    printf("CUDA ERROR: Unable to allocate device-side data.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return Mdevice;
}

int *read_ppm(char *filename, int *xsize, int *ysize, int *maxval) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s' cannot be opened\n", filename);
        return NULL;
    }
    char first_line[4];
    fgets(first_line, 4, fp);
    if (strcmp(first_line, "P6\n")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s' not in P6 format\n", filename);
        return NULL;
    }
    char temp;
    while ((temp = fgetc(fp)) == '#') {
        fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]\n"); //skip until newline
    }
    ungetc(temp, fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n%d", xsize, ysize, maxval);
    fgetc(fp); // skip the newline character following maxval
    
    int *pic = (int*)malloc((*xsize)*(*ysize)*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < (*xsize) * (*ysize); i++) {
        unsigned char buf[3];
        fread((void*)&buf[0], sizeof(unsigned char), 3, fp);
        pic[i] = buf[0];
    }
    return pic;
}

void write_ppm( char *filename, int xsize, int ysize, int maxval, int *pic) 
{
    FILE *fp;
      
    fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!fp) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "FAILED TO OPEN FILE '%s' for writing\n", filename);
        exit(-1); 
    }
  
    fprintf(fp, "P6\n"); 
    fprintf(fp,"%d %d\n%d\n", xsize, ysize, maxval);
  
    int numpix = xsize * ysize;
    for (int i=0; i<numpix; i++) {
        unsigned char uc = (unsigned char) pic[i];
        fprintf(fp, "%c%c%c", uc, uc, uc); 
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

Matrix AllocateMatrix(int height, int width, int init, int *data)
{
  Matrix M;
  M.width = width;
  M.height = height;
  int size = M.width * M.height;
  M.elements = NULL;
    
  // don't allocate memory on option 2
  if(init == 2)
    return M;
        
  M.elements = (int*) malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    //create the sobel filter
    if (init == 1)
    {
  for(int i = 0; i < M.height; i++)
    {
            //for(unsigned int j = 0; j < M.width; j++)
            //{
                //M.elements[i] = (init == 0) ? (0.0f) : (rand()*3 / (float)RAND_MAX);
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    M.elements[i*M.width + 0] = 2;
                    M.elements[i*M.width + 1] = 0;
                    M.elements[i*M.width + 2] = -2;
                }
                else
                {
                    M.elements[i*M.width + 0] = 1;
                    M.elements[i*M.width + 1] = 0;
                    M.elements[i*M.width + 2] = -1;
                }
        }
    }
        else if (init == 3)
        {
            M.elements[0] = 1;
            M.elements[1] = 2;
            M.elements[2] = 1;
            M.elements[3] = 0;
            M.elements[4] = 0;
            M.elements[5] = 0;
            M.elements[6] = -1;
            M.elements[7] = -2;
            M.elements[8] = -1;
                
            }
        else if (init == 4)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < M.height; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < M.width; j++)
                {
                    M.elements[i*M.width+j] = data[i*M.width+j];
                }
            }
        }
            //}
      
    
  return M;
}

Matrix AllocateMatrix(int height, int width, int init)
{
  Matrix M;
  M.width = width;
  M.height = height;
  int size = M.width * M.height;
  M.elements = NULL;
  // only allocate memory on option 2
  if(init == 2)
    {
        M.elements = (int*) malloc(size*sizeof(int));
        memset(M.elements, 0, size*sizeof(int));
    return M;
    }   
  M.elements = (int*) malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    
    //create the sobel filter
    if (init == 1)
    {
  for(int i = 0; i < M.height; i++)
    {
            //for(unsigned int j = 0; j < M.width; j++)
            //{
                //M.elements[i] = (init == 0) ? (0.0f) : (rand()*3 / (float)RAND_MAX);
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    M.elements[i*M.width + 0] = 2;
                    M.elements[i*M.width + 1] = 0;
                    M.elements[i*M.width + 2] = -2;
                }
                else
                {
                    M.elements[i*M.width + 0] = 1;
                    M.elements[i*M.width + 1] = 0;
                    M.elements[i*M.width + 2] = -1;
                }
        }
    }
        else if (init == 3)
        {
            M.elements[0] = 1;
            M.elements[1] = 2;
            M.elements[2] = 1;
            M.elements[3] = 0;
            M.elements[4] = 0;
            M.elements[5] = 0;
            M.elements[6] = -1;
            M.elements[7] = -2;
            M.elements[8] = -1;
                
        }
    return M;
}

void CopyToDeviceMatrix(Matrix Mdevice, const Matrix Mhost)
{
  int size = Mhost.width * Mhost.height * sizeof(int);
  Mdevice.height = Mhost.height;
  Mdevice.width = Mhost.width;
  if(cudaMemcpy(Mdevice.elements, Mhost.elements, size, 
         cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess)
       {
          printf("CUDA ERROR: Unable to copy counter to device.\n");
          exit(1);
       }
}

void FreeDeviceMatrix(Matrix* M)
{
  cudaFree(M->elements);
  M->elements = NULL;
}

Matrix convolutionOnDevice(int *pic, Matrix P)
{
  unsigned char cudaFail = 1;  //  Host-side flag for error testing.
  unsigned char* cudaFail_d; //  Device-side flag for error testing.
  cudaError_t cudaErr;
    unsigned int *pic_device;
    Matrix pic_mtx;
    Matrix pic_mtx_d;
    pic_mtx = AllocateMatrix(P.height, P.width, 4, pic);
    printf("pic mtx: %d\n",pic_mtx.elements[34445]);
    pic_mtx_d = AllocateDeviceMatrix(pic_mtx);
    CopyToDeviceMatrix(pic_mtx_d, pic_mtx);

  // Allocate P on the device
  Matrix Pd = AllocateDeviceMatrix(P);
  CopyToDeviceMatrix(Pd, P); // Clear memory
  // Setup the execution configuration
  int tile_width = 14;
  int num_threads_per_block = tile_width+(MASK_WIDTH-1);
  dim3 blockDim(num_threads_per_block,num_threads_per_block,1);
 
  dim3 gridDim((P.width/float(tile_width))+1, (P.height/float(tile_width))+1,1);
    //dim3 blockDim(10,10,1);
 
  //dim3 gridDim(2,2,1);
  printf("M height: %d, M width: %d\n", pic_mtx.height, pic_mtx.width);

    Matrix Mask_x;
    Matrix Mask_y;
    Matrix mask_dx;
    Matrix mask_dy;
    Mask_x = AllocateMatrix(MASK_WIDTH, MASK_WIDTH, 1);
    Mask_y = AllocateMatrix(MASK_WIDTH, MASK_WIDTH, 3);

  mask_dx = AllocateDeviceMatrix(Mask_x);
    //mask_dy = AllocateDeviceMatrix(Mask_y);
    
  CopyToDeviceMatrix(mask_dx, Mask_x); // Clear memory
    //cudaMemcpyToSymbol(Mcx, Mask.elements, MASK_WIDTH*MASK_WIDTH*sizeof(int));
    //printf("mask: [[%d],[%d],[%d];\n [%d],[%d],[%d];\n [%d],[%d],[%d]]\n", Mask_x.elements[0],Mask_x.elements[1],Mask_x.elements[2],Mask_x.elements[3],Mask_x.elements[4],Mask_x.elements[5],Mask_x.elements[6],Mask_x.elements[7],Mask_x.elements[8],Mask_x.elements[9]);
  convolveKernel<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(pic_mtx_d, Pd, mask_dx, cudaFail_d);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaErr = cudaGetLastError();//  Retrieve built-in device-side error signal.
  if(cudaErr != cudaSuccess)    //  Something went wrong on the device. CUDA reports it here.
  {
    printf("CUDA ERROR: Kernel failed.\n");
    printf("  %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaErr));
    exit(1);
  }
  if(cudaFail == 0)    //  Does your custom error flag indicate failure?
  {
    printf("CUSTOM ERROR: Kernel failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }  
    printf("x direction done!\n");
  // Launch the device computation threads!
  // Read P from the device
  CopyFromDeviceMatrix(P, Pd);
/*
    CopyToDeviceMatrix(Pd, P);
    CopyToDeviceMatrix(mask_dy, Mask_y); // Clear memory
    convolveKernel<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(pic_mtx_d, Pd, mask_dy, cudaFail_d);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaErr = cudaGetLastError();//  Retrieve built-in device-side error signal.
  if(cudaErr != cudaSuccess)    //  Something went wrong on the device. CUDA reports it here.
  {
    printf("CUDA ERROR: Kernel failed.\n");
    printf("  %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaErr));
    exit(1);
  }
  if(cudaFail == 0)    //  Does your custom error flag indicate failure?
  {
    printf("CUSTOM ERROR: Kernel failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }  
  // Launch the device computation threads!
  // Read P from the device
  CopyFromDeviceMatrix(P, Pd); 

  printf("y direction done!\n");
    */
  // Free device matrices
  FreeDeviceMatrix(&pic_mtx_d);
  FreeDeviceMatrix(&Pd);
    
    return P;
}

// Copy a device matrix to a host matrix.
void CopyFromDeviceMatrix(Matrix Mhost, const Matrix Mdevice)
{
    printf("Mdevice.width: %d\n", Mdevice.width);
    printf("Mdevice.height: %d\n", Mdevice.height);
  int size = Mdevice.width * Mdevice.height * sizeof(int);
  if(cudaMemcpy(Mhost.elements, Mdevice.elements, size, 
         cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) != cudaSuccess)
       {
          printf("CUDA ERROR: Unable to copy counter from device.\n");
          exit(1);
       }
}
void FreeMatrix(Matrix* M)
{
  free(M->elements);
  M->elements = NULL;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int thresh = DEFAULT_THRESHOLD;
    char *filename;
    filename = strdup( DEFAULT_FILENAME);
  
    if (argc > 1) {
        if (argc == 3)  { // filename AND threshold
            filename = strdup( argv[1]);
            thresh = atoi( argv[2] );
        }
        if (argc == 2) { // default file but specified threshhold
            thresh = atoi( argv[1] );
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "file %s    threshold %d\n", filename, thresh); 
    }

    int xsize, ysize, maxval;
    int *pic = read_ppm( filename, &xsize, &ysize, &maxval ); 
    
    int numbytes =  xsize * ysize * 3 * sizeof( int );
    int *result = (int *) malloc( numbytes );
    if (!result) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "sobel() unable to malloc %d bytes\n", numbytes);
        exit(-1); // fail
    }

    int i, j, magnitude, sum1, sum2; 
    
    memset(result, 0, xsize * ysize * sizeof(int));

// cpu implementation 
    for (i = 1;  i < ysize - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < xsize -1; j++) {
      
            int offset = i*xsize + j;

            sum1 =  pic[ xsize * (i-1) + j+1 ] -     pic[ xsize*(i-1) + j-1 ] 
            + 2 * pic[ xsize * (i)   + j+1 ] - 2 * pic[ xsize*(i)   + j-1 ]
            +     pic[ xsize * (i+1) + j+1 ] -     pic[ xsize*(i+1) + j-1 ];
      
            sum2 = pic[ xsize * (i-1) + j-1 ] + 2 * pic[ xsize * (i-1) + j ]  + pic[ xsize * (i-1) + j+1 ]
                - pic[xsize * (i+1) + j-1 ] - 2 * pic[ xsize * (i+1) + j ] - pic[ xsize * (i+1) + j+1 ];
      
            magnitude =  sum1*sum1;// + sum2*sum2;

            if (magnitude > thresh)
                result[offset] = 255;
            else 
                result[offset] = 0;
        }
    }
    Matrix P;
    //Matrix M;

    P  = AllocateMatrix(xsize, ysize, 2);
    //M = AllocateMatrix(xsize, ysize, 2);
    //printf("P before gpu: %d\n", P.elements[0]);
  convolutionOnDevice(pic, P);
    
    write_ppm( (char *) "result8000gold.ppm", xsize, ysize, 255, result);
    write_ppm( (char *) "result8000gpu.ppm", P.height, P.width, 255, P.elements);
  size_t n = sizeof(P.elements);
    // TO-DO: de-allocate !!!!

    fprintf(stderr, "sobel done\n"); 
    //FreeMatrix(&M);
        free(pic);
        pic = NULL;
        FreeMatrix(&P);
}
```

Input image:
[image]

Out image:
[image]

I am trying to implement the sobel filter by having a larger input window (that have the so called "halo" elements), and a smaller output window to handle boundary condtions

Comment: Shouldn't `int row_i = row_o - 1;` be `int row_i = row_o - (MASK_WIDTH-1)/2;`? Same for `col_i`.

Comment: @paleonix thanks for the reply! I was debugging some stuff, so I hardcoded a few values. For a mask width of 3, (MASK_WIDTH-1)/2 will be 1.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. It turns out that I had the width and height mixed up for the input and output arrays!